# strange results of page visit tracking code

Tags: php

On several pages I have this code to track the visits:

```
$url = "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]";
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if (strpos($ip, '95.180.') !== false) {$canbe = 'sky';}
elseif (strpos($ip, '109.122.') !== false) {$canbe = 'sea';}
elseif (strpos($ip, '79.101.') !== false) {$canbe = 'earth';}
else {$canbe = 'unknown';}

    try {
        $sql = "insert into stat (ip, url, canbe) values (:aip, :aurl, :acanbe)";
        $st = $db->prepare($sql);
        $st->execute([
            ":aip" => $ip,
            ":aurl" => $url,
            ":acanbe" => $canbe
        ]);
    }
    catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Usually it works fine, but sometimes in column `url` I'm getting very strange results, for examle:

`http://abcmemento.se/smizla/img/jquery-3.2.1.min.js`
`http://abcmemento.se/smizla/img/indexb.js`
`http://abcmemento.se/smizla/img/ico/02.png`
`http://abcmemento.se/sftp-config.json`

So I'm getting resources i.e. `images`, `javascript` files, even `json` files which doesn't exists at all.

Also, in case of existing image - its path is displayed wrong.

Crazy, isn't it?

Comment: Do you have any conditions in your .htaccess that may have cause this ? 
Is your script is under the same tld ?